# Convert DStream to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How can I convert a *DStream* to an *RDD*?
I know that we can use `transform` or `forEachRDD` method to manipulate underlying *rdd* of *dstream*, but I want to use *rdd* inside the driver. For example to add in a queue like last lines in the
[QueueStream Example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/QueueStream.scala)

Comment: Not sure I understand why you need this exactly. But, you cannot convert a dstream into a single rdd as dstream is infinite and constructed from many small rdds which are generated every batch interval. Am I m missing your question?

Comment: I want to add RDD members to some list at driver and restore it again in new batch. is there anything like `collect` for dstreams?